# DOM point interpreted as object in chrome

Tags: javascript, svg, dom

The following, rather silly, code works fine in Firefox, but in chrome what is indicated in the comments happens. Wanted to check the SVG functionality, so I'm checking if the center of an ellipse is point in fill of that ellipse, which is obviously true. The puzzling fact are the first two console logs. The Dom point output as "Dom point", and then its typeof as object, which naturally breaks the next two console.log statements.

```
let ellipseFirstStop = document.getElementById("Sation_1_circle"); //Sation_1_circle is an SVG ellipse.
let centroFirstStop = new DOMPoint(+ellipseFirstStop.cx.animVal.value, +ellipseFirstStop.cy.animVal.value);

console.log(centroFirstStop);
//outputs DOMPoint {x: 268.2749938964844, y: 183.63299560546875, z: 0, w: 1}, all fine.

console.log(typeof centroFirstStop);
//outputs "object", what?

console.log("is point in fill test: "+ellipseFirstStop.isPointInFill(centroFirstStop));
//causes: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'isPointInFill' on 'SVGGeometryElement' parameter 1 is not of type 'SVGPoint'.

console.log("is point in fill test: "+ellipseFirstStop.isPointInFill(new DOMPoint(+ellipseFirstStop.cx.animVal.value, +ellipseFirstStop.cy.animVal.value)));
//causes: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'isPointInFill' on 'SVGGeometryElement': parameter 1 is not of type 'SVGPoint'.
```

Comment: [`DOMPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint) != [`SVGPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPoint)

Comment: I understand your point, but I'm explicitly creating a DOM point giving it values retrieved from the SVG, and the first console.log confirms that this is a DOM point :s

Comment: I don't think you do get my point. You're creating a `DOMPoint` object. Then you're passing that into a method that only accepts `SVGPoint` objects, and is telling you that with the quite clear error message `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'isPointInFill' on 'SVGGeometryElement' parameter 1 is not of type 'SVGPoint'.`. It doesn't make any differences where `x` and `y` come from. It's that you're passing it the wrong kind of object. It's nice that Firefox doesn't care, but Chrome apparently does and is telling you exactly what's wrong. Create an `SVGPoint` instead.

Comment: Sorry. Was reading too fast.
trying now:
let mySVGPoint = ellipseFirstStop.createSVGPoint();
gives me createSVGPoint() is not a function :'(

Comment: That tells me athat whatever `ellipseFirstStep` is, it's not an `svg` element. Perhaps you've forgotten to use the SVG namespace? If I do `const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");`, the resulting element has `createSVGPoint` and other SVG-isms. (If you forget the namespace, it won't; [more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg).) Please update your question with a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: You need an <svg> element not an ellipse. createSVGPoint is on the SVGSVGElement interface

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The interface for isPointInFill used to be an SVGPoint, it was [changed to DOMPointInit](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/389).

The advantage of DOMPointInit is that you can pass either a DOMPoint or an SVGPoint to the API and it will still work, as will basically any object that has x and y properties.

Firefox has implemented the new API, Chrome has not yet.

If you pass an SVGPoint that you can get via [SVGSVGElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement).createSVGPoint() your code will work in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I don't think I'd have figured it out myself, when I read: document.getElementById("SVG-ElementID").createSVGPoint(); I assumed an SVG elemnt would be "any" svg element or "sub element" so to speak. And when I check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement there's no reference to "createSVGPoint as one of its methods.
Is this all a little obscure or am I just not following a systematic enough learning curve? If so, what resources would you recommend for making my learning more systematic?

Comment: The SVGElement interface is the common base class for all SVG Elements. You want the [SVGSVGElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement) interface that is the interface specifically for <svg> elements. That's where createSVGPoint is found. You'll need to get the DOM for your root <svg> element and use that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again, bad reading comprehension on my part again, sorry. Now I see SVGSVGElement != SVGElement. I'll do my best to put more attention on my reading.

Comment: #hints
let point = document.getElementById("svg").createSVGPoint();
point.x = x;
point.y = y;
circle.isPointInStroke(point)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both of you. Got my code working in both chrome and firefoxthanks to your help :) the last console.log returns true when I check if the centre of the ellipse lays on the path.

```html
<svg id="mySVG" width="200" height="250" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<ellipse id="myEllipse" cx="75" cy="75" rx="20" ry="5" stroke="red" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
<path id="myPath" d="M20,230 L75,75 l90,90" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5"/>

</svg>

<script>

//

   let myPath = document.getElementById("myPath");
    let myEllipse = document.getElementById("myEllipse");
    let mySVGPoint = document.getElementById("mySVG").createSVGPoint();
    mySVGPoint.y = myEllipse.cx.animVal.value;
    mySVGPoint.x = myEllipse.cy.animVal.value;

    console.log(`Point at ${mySVGPoint.x}, ${mySVGPoint.y}:`, myPath.isPointInStroke(mySVGPoint));





</script>
```